# Python Asyncio schedule tasks weekly

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio, schedule

I am writing a discord bot in Python, which already has the two async overwritten methods on_ready and on_message to react to messages in a certain way.

Now I wanted to add a function, which should be called once in a week. I tried something with asyncio.sleep() but I don't want to start the bot at that specific time and then sleep 604.800 sec (1 week in seconds) to repeat that function every week.

Here's what I got so far:

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        #some initial stuff
        self.loop.create_task(self.routine())

    async def on_message(self, message):
        #reply to chat messages
        await message.channel.send("Reply")

    async def routine(self):
        while True:
            print("I'm on that routine boi")
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

It works so far, that I can use the bot in discord and get the outputs every 3 seconds.
But I'd prefer something like from the [schedule module](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) to use something like

```
scheduler.every().sunday.at("8:55").do(self.routine())
```

Any chance to do something similar in combination with asyncio?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't do this using a cron job?

Comment: @nageeb Yes, I can't  do it like that, because I start the script once and it should keep running 24/7 to work as a discord bot on a remote server. With that I could do my "weekly routine" perfectly, but the bot would only work on Sundays, which is not what I want / anyone would want.

Answer (score 1):

The Event loop provides mechanisms to schedule callback functions to be called at some point in the future, as shown [here in Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#scheduling-callbacks)

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        #some initial stuff
        self.loop.create_task(self.routine())

    async def on_message(self, message):
        #reply to chat messages
        await message.channel.send("Reply")

   async def execute():
         res = await loop.call_later(delay, callback, *args)
         delay += delay + 604800 
         return res



    async def routine(self):
        while True:
            print("I'm on that routine boi")
            res = await loop.run_until_complete(execute)
```

Comment: mhm yeah, but this does quite the same as asyncio.sleep(604800) which is not the best solution for me. This would mean that I have to start the script exactly at that time where I want it to do the routine in a week again. So if I start the script and want to make quick changes in the code, I gotta stop the script and wait until next Sunday.

Comment: I did some changes that I think fix your need

Comment: but i still can‘t schedule for the future and THEN repeat every week, right?